# How can I obtain old Debian package metadata?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I'm looking at `snapshot.debian.org`, and I'd like to find some metadata for some packages on a certain day of 2020. Say, for example, that I want the metadata for buster on Nov. 1 2020. Where do I find the "Packages" file that holds the metadata that I would have gotten, had I run `apt-get update` on that date?

The search functions are quite nice for finding packages, but I don't see any mention of the Release/Packages files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up [the month you’re interested in](https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/?year=2020;month=11), pick one of the snapshots for the given day, and either use that as a `deb` line or go hunting for the relevant metadata. For example, you’ll find [the `Release` files for the last Bullseye on November 1<sup>st</sup> here](https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20201101T210343Z/dists/bullseye/), and [the corresponding `Package` files for `amd64` in `main` here](https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20201101T210343Z/dists/bullseye/main/binary-amd64/).

```
deb     https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20201101T210343Z/ bullseye main
```

will allow `apt` to retrieve and use that metadata.

(See [the “Usage” section on the main snapshot.debian.org page](https://snapshot.debian.org/) for details.)